# chrome.storage API not working in my Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension which opens camera. When I reload the page, I want to show camera again. I used Chrome's [chrome.storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/), but in the Console, there is an error: `key is not defined`. What is the problem with my usage of `chrome.storage`?

**This is my JavaScript code in `content.js`:**

```js
chrome.storage.local.get(['key', 'keyHtml'], function (result) {

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true,
  }).then(mediaStream => {
    key.srcObject = mediaStream;
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.warn(error);
  });

  result.key;
  document.body.innerHTML += keyHtml;
});
```

**This is my code in background.js:**

```js
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { ShowCamera: 'true' });
  let html = `
  <div class = "video-container">        
    <video style="width: 240px; margin: 0px;" autoplay="true" id="videoElement"></div>
  </div>`;

  let vid = document.querySelector('#videoElement');

  chrome.storage.local.set({ key: vid }, function () {});
  chrome.storage.local.set({ keyHtml: html });
});
```

Comment: 1. Storage can't store DOM elements like `vid`, it can only store simple types like strings/numbers and arrays or objects of such types, 2. `key.srcObject` is invalid code because there is no variable `key` in your code 3. `result.key;` does nothing at all. As you can see you'll probably have to rethink the entire flow of your extension because messaging cannot transfer DOM elements.

Comment: To debug, run `chrome.storage.local.get(function(items) { console.log(items) });` to see if you actually have the key/value in your Storage